# How to add only superscript number do not add words in the text?

Tags: biblatex

[image]

This is wrong, how to delete the quoted text.

Comment: https://medphys.msubmit.net/cgi-bin/main.plex?form_type=do_cat&file_nm=medphys_latex_template.html  This is the link to the file

Comment: As a matter of courtesy and so that the question and answer will be useful to future visitors to this site, your question should be self-contained and not rely on links to external sites.

Answer (score 1):

Your [template](https://medphys.msubmit.net/cgi-bin/main.plex?form_type=do_cat&file_nm=medphys_latex_template.html) has

```
\usepackage{showkeys}
```

in the preamble (line 22). This shows the keys associated with label and citation. You can remove or comment out the above line.